# Restful wcf Service image upload

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

Rest Wcf Serivce accepts image upload.
it accepts image as base64string.
I have created a simple aspx page to upload the image.
But I am getting a lot of errors. "Some time Chanel Factory is not available"
"There is no endpoint listening" sort of errors.
here are my web.config files. I dont understand what mistake I am doing.
Any help will be appreciated.
Currently service and client are located on my local system.

Client Web.config file

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="WebHttpBinding_Service">
          <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
            messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          </textMessageEncoding>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding_Service"
        contract="ServiceReference1.Service" name="WebHttpBinding_Service" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors> 
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

---

REST wcf Service Web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior1" name="Service">
                <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IService" behaviorConfiguration="REST">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost"/>
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="REST">
                    <webHttp/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceBehavior1">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

The client and server endpoint configurations don't match. On the service, you have an endpoint with "webHttpBinding" and a behavior configuraiton which contains the `<webHttp/>` behavior. On the client you have a custom binding which is not equivalent to the `webHttpBinding`, and no behaviors.

The problem seems to be that REST endpoints *do not expose metadata*, so "Add Service Reference" doesn't work well for them. Try either copying the contract and the binding configuration to the client, or if it's just a simple "upload" service, you can use something simpler than WCF, such as the `WebClient` class.

Comment: I just want to upload an image as base64String to WCF service in order to test it, Is there any REST clients available that I can test the above scenario.

Comment: You can use a WCF client for it as well, but you'll have to update the generated config and the contract manually.